# Long delay to download images

Tags: cordova, networking, google-chrome-devtools

I'm getting a delay to download images (5-10s) in a mobile app when images are loaded for the first time during the app session. The behavior is that the images don't render for a number of seconds, often significantly longer than the time it takes to load the image after the first byte is received from the server. Bear with me if this feels incomplete, I'm hoping to also get an idea of where to look for the source of the problem. This is part of a related problem (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70635835/long-response-time-for-cloudfront-misses)) with the cdn that's serving the images, so that's at least part of the problem. But there's a problem with the app itself downloading the images slowly, and that's what I want to discuss here. I've included a screenshot of what the network tab shows for one of these occurrences.

[image: dev tools stalled image]

You can see the "stalled" period takes a long time, but at other times it's even (much) longer than the TTFB, sometimes it's 5-6s. This is for a mobile app built using cordova. The cdn that serves the images currently uses http2 but in the past it was on http1.1 and we didn't see this problem. However we've tried going back to http1.1 but got mixed results; on some devices the delay became minimal, but on other devices it didn't make a difference. I've tried using charles proxy (similar to wireshark) to watch the requests and what I saw matched only the TTFB portion of what dev tools showed (i.e. the 2-3s period to complete the request, but not the period that shows as "stalled" in dev tools). In essence it seems the webview or device is delaying some requests from going out, but I can't figure out why or how to prevent it. Usually the app has other requests that may be running when the images are loading, and dev tools marks the image requests as low priority. So I've tried turning off those requests to allow the webview to only focus on the images, but the delay didn't go away. How can I optimize the loading of images to minimize this occurrence? How else can I debug this problem?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the painting of the images? Seems like it's more network related and slow rendering

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a screenshot of the painting of the images? Rendering would only happen after the image has started downloading, so it wouldn't be affected by the "stalled" period. Or is that incorrect?

Comment: Then it is a network issue and has nothing to do with codova. Your title states "long delay to render" but it's actually "long delay to download"

Comment: Thanks you're right I've updated the title. Any ideas as to what may be causing the delay to download, particularly the "stalled" period?

Comment: Does the CDN behave properly with a regular browser?